# Laravel using ajax get records from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

Am trying to get data from controller and append to "tbody" using Ajax, yet am getting blank page.

Controller:

```
public function getRecordsMD(){

    $filedata = File::where('uploaded_by', '=', auth()->user()->username)->get();
    return response()->json([
        'filedata'=>$filedata,
    ]);
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/manage_document',[utemfilesharing::class, 'getRecordsMD']);
```

Ajax/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
getRecordsMD();

//Get all records
function getRecordsMD() {
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/manage_document',
          dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data.filedata);
          $.each(data.filedata, function (key, item) { 
             $('tbody').append('<tr>\
              <td>'+item.id+'</td>\
              <td>'+item.name+'</td>\
              <td>'+item.faculity_name+'</td>\
              <td>'+item.document_type+'</td>\
              <td>'+item.subject_name+'</td>\
              <td>'+item.description+'</td>\
              <td>\
                <button type="button" id="editFiles" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-model" data-id="'+item.id+'"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>\
                <button type="button" id="deleteFiles" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#delete-model" data-id="'+item.id+'"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>\
              </td>\
            </tr>');
          });
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error:', data);
          }
    });
}
});
```

View:

```
<!-- Manage Document -->
<div class="col-xl-12 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
        <div
            class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Manage Document</h6>
        </div>
        <!-- Card Body -->
        
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="successMsg" style="display: none" >
            File Updated successfully! 
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="successDMsg" style="display: none" >
            File Delete successfully! 
        </div>
             <table id="manageDocument" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
             <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>Faculity Name</th>
                        <th>Document Type</th>
                        <th>Subject Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="{{asset('vendor\bootstrap\js\bootstrap5-1-3.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('vendor\jquery\jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js\Models.js')}}"></script>
```

It seems like am missing something I don't know what its. whenever I navigate to /manage_document I get a blank page where it suppose display the table. will be glad if you help.

Comment: Is there any output from the `console.log()` ? ... also while there, see if there are any obvious javascript errors logging. Then also check the browser's network tab to see if the `manage_document` requests are going through, and the response can be checked in this area too.

Comment: It seems the ajax cant get to controller. Am receiving nothing in the console

Comment: In the controller, before the `return`, add a `dd($filedata);` to see if it reaches that point.

Comment: Yes I did, am getting the response json $filedata when I check the browser response tap that means the controller is working. but the thing is am not able to retrieve it in ajax append tbody or even print it as console.log.

Comment: Still need to know, from the browser's network tab, was is the code at the far left of row that has `manage_document` after making the request ... if you click that row, then you can also check the response tab on the right. (clear the network tab before making the request, to eliminate what might already appear from other requests)